# Trigger behavior is not consistent if it is invoked by multiple thread from java Application

Tags: oracle

I want particular section of my trigger to be executed one by one in case of multiple thread from java application perform update which results invocation of trigger .

```
create or replace TRIGGER TA_TB_BATCHFILE_UPD
BEFORE UPDATE OF EOM_ORDER_RESULT ON TB_SERVICEORDER
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT NUMBER(6) :=0;
BEGIN
IF :NEW.BATCH_FILE_ID IS NOT NULL AND (NVL(:OLD.EOM_ORDER_RESULT,'X') != NVL(:NEW.EOM_ORDER_RESULT,'X'))
THEN
SELECT  PROCESSED_ORDERS INTO PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT FROM TB_BATCHFILE WHERE BATCH_FILE_ID = :NEW.BATCH_FILE_ID FOR UPDATE of PROCESSED_ORDERS;
IF PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT is NULL
then
PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT:=1;
ELSE
PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT := PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT+1;
END IF;
UPDATE TB_BATCHFILE E SET E.PROCESSED_ORDERS = PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT ,E.PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP = SYSTIMESTAMP WHERE E.BATCH_FILE_ID=:NEW.BATCH_FILE_ID ;
END IF;
END TA_TB_BATCHFILE_UPD;
```

I want below piece of code to be executed one by one.

```
SELECT  PROCESSED_ORDERS INTO PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT FROM TB_BATCHFILE WHERE BATCH_FILE_ID = :NEW.BATCH_FILE_ID ;
IF PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT is NULL
then
PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT:=1;
ELSE
PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT := PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT+1;
END IF;
UPDATE TB_BATCHFILE E SET E.PROCESSED_ORDERS = PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT ,E.PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP = SYSTIMESTAMP WHERE E.BATCH_FILE_ID=:NEW.BATCH_FILE_ID ;
```

Comment: Concurrent programming is hard. You need to design an architecture to support it. If you need to serialise a chunk of your process you probably shouldn't be using a trigger. Maybe a job or a queue would be better.

Comment: This is one of the reasons you really shouldn't use triggers, or especially depend on the order of the firing of triggers.  However, perhaps your process would work this way.   Instead of grabbing the value and increment it, just `UPDATE ... SET E.PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT = NVL(E.PROCESSED_ORDERS_COUNT,0) + 1 ...`

Comment: Thanks for the response . but even that work around does not work . 13 update made simultaneously on EOM_ORDER_RESULT where as only 9 increment could happen to processed_orders.